# Point in time queries in kdb

Tags: kdb

I often need to select the last row in a partitioned table, up to a certain time. This is what I use:

```
select last A,last B,last C from mytable where date=2013.05.23,ts<10:30:00,A in (`Bob`Jane)
```

This query probably loads all `Bob`Jane rows up to 10:30:00, then returns the last row. Is there a more efficient way to run point-in-time queries in kdb?

Some benchmark data for my table:

```
/select all data
\t t: select ...
1724i

count t
2225311i

\t select ... ts<15:00:00
2040i

\t select ... ts<12:00:00
1092i

\t select ... ts<10:00:00
521i
```

Comment: The `where` clause shouldn't return all rows; at worst it should only produce the list of valid indices. Are you seeing some dramatic slow-down with this query versus what you expect? How is this table structured anyway? Is it all in memory? Splayed? Partitioned?

Comment: @chrisaycock Added more information to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative is to use the following:

```
select A,B,C from mytable where date=2013.05.23,ts<10:30:00,A in (`Bob`Jane),i=last i
```

Although I doubt there will be any performance improvement from what you currently have.

What's more important is the type of table (in memory/ splayed/ partitioned (including how it's partitioned)) and the attributes (if any) that are used.

Comment: It's a partitioned, splayed table. I added more information to the question.

Comment: Do you have any attributes set?

Comment: Not that I know. It's partitioned table, indexed by ts. I only need to run a point-in-time query on a specific date.

Comment: Using [meta](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/meta) will give you an indication of what columns have attributes. If you really want to take full advatage of kdb+, I strongly suggest using [attributes](http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:QforMortals2/tables#Attributes) if you're data set is sufficiently large.

Comment: If the table is indexed by ts, isn't it possible for kdb to locate the last row matching the requested time-stamp, then walk sequentially backward on the table to find the last available observation matching the select conditions?

Answer (score 1):

`aj` provides the functionality that you are looking for:

http://code.kx.com/q/ref/joins/#aj-aj0-asof-join

There are some performance tips for `aj` at the link provided.

Comment: The OP is asking for a query. An asof-join will produce a new table.

Comment: Correct, I don't need to join data from two different tables. Can you post a query example using aj, I can try to benchmark it.

Comment: You can construct a query table as input. There is a functioning example at the link.